# Appending items to different lists based on conditions

Tags: python, list

Basically I am looking for a method of appending items from a list into two different lists based on certain conditions.

I have a rather extensive python 3.3 program that manages an online chat interface.  If we have a set list of users, for example `['bob', 'joe', 'frank', 'jimmy', 'louis']`, they are either offline or offline. I want to append all of the online users to one list, and the offline users to another so if bob and joe are online, then they would be appended to the list "online" and the rest would be appended to the list "offline". After, I would do something like:

```
print('online: %s offline: %s' % (', '.join(online), ', '.join(offline))
```

If you could tell me a efficient way of doing this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you want efficiency, you'll have to be more precise on how your data is stored. IS there another list with users status?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want to partition an input list in two, depending on the connection state of the users. Assuming that there's some function to determine if an user is online:

```
users   = ['bob', 'joe', 'frank', 'jimmy', 'louis']
online  = [x for x in users if is_online(x)]
offline = [x for x in users if not is_online(x)]
```

Comment: To avoid inconsistent results if a user changes state, you might do `[x for x in users if x not in online]` instead. This could still be wrong, but at least it won't ever be self-contradictory!

Comment: You can not name both the list and the function `online`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a `defaultdict(list)` and append to it based on your criteria - this will also scale nicely to busy/away/DND etc..., and then access that via the status you want:

```
from random import choice
from collections import defaultdict

status_choice = ['online', 'offline']
statuses = defaultdict(list)

for name in ['bob', 'joe', 'frank', 'jimmy', 'louis']:
    status = choice(status_choice)
    statuses[status].append(name)

print(statuses)
# defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'offline': ['joe', 'frank', 'jimmy', 'louis'], 'online': ['bob']})
print(statuses['online'])
# ['bob']
```

You may also wish to consider using a `set` instead of a list for quicker lookup/removal/insertion of names and it will also stop duplictate values occurring.

Answer (score 1):

I used something like this once:

```
def partition(seq, predicate, if_true, if_false):
    select = if_false, if_true
    for each in seq:
        select[predicate(each)](each)

def divisible_by_3(n):
    return n % 3 == 0

div3s = []
nondiv3s = []

partition(range(1, 11), divisible_by_3, div3s.append, nondiv3s.append)

print div3s, nondiv3s
```

Result:

```
[3, 6, 9] [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your application is going to maintain the lists of online and offline users for some time, with the contents changing as users come on or go off line, I think an approach using sets is best:

```
online_users = set(initial_online_users)
offline_users = set(all_users) - online_users

def come_online(user):
    offline_users.remove(user)
    online_users.add(user)

def go_offline(user):
    online_users.remove(user)
    offline_users.add(user)
```

The operations to move a user from online to offline or visa versa will be very fast, even if the number of total users is large. The order of additions and removals in each is chosen to ensure that an exception will be raised if an unknown user gets passed in (without the user getting added anywhere).

Answer (score 0):

This will be much faster for long (>100) lists while ensuring a user does not end up in both or neither lists:

```
users   = ['bob', 'joe', 'frank', 'jimmy', 'louis']
offline = []
online = filter(None, [u if is_online(u) else offline.append(u) for u in users])
```

Comment: I feel like constructing a list with a bunch of `None`s then filtering them out is way more work than just constructing one list from the exclusion of the other list.

Comment: Profiling is better than feeling.

Comment: For a long list (> 100's) of users my method is 100 times faster.

Comment: It's also almost unreadable. If `n` is big and speed is a priority constructing the list on the fly is a bad idea in any case, so you're optimizing the wrong solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my stab at it.

It's a little easier to read but as the other answers demonstrate it can be trimmed down further if that is your preference.

This example builds a function (***getUserStatus(user_list)***) that returns the two lists (*online/offline*) within a main list (*[["online1", "online2"], ["offline1", "offline2"]]*) . You can access each list using the corresponding index numbers as demonstrated in ***printUserStatus(user_status)***. The ***printUserStatus(user_status)*** function  formats the two lists into a string, based on your example above, and returns the result. You will need to fill in the ***userIsOnline(name)*** funciton with your logic to check if your user is online/offline. The ***userIsOnline(name)*** function must return a boolean value (***True/False***) for it to work.

See the example below for the usage example:

```
online  = []
offline = []
users   = ['bob', 'joe', 'frank', 'jimmy', 'louis']

def userIsOnline(name):
    # your status check logic here
    return True #or False

def getUserStatus(user_list):
    for name in user_list:
        if userIsOnline(name):
            online.append(name)
        else:
            offline.append(name)
    return [online, offline]

def printUserStatus(user_status):
    on  = ', '.join(user_status[0])
    off = ', '.join(user_status[1])
    return 'online: %s offline: %s' % (on, off)

# Example usage
status = getUserStatus(users)
print(printUserStatus(status))
```